# Change Integer to Price with PHP

Tags: php

I have an integer of `30000`. I'd like to change this to appear as `30,000`.

Can someone explain how I do this with PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: string money_format ( string $format , float $number )

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.money-format.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `number_format` or `money_format`. Refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
<?php echo number_format(30000); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `number_format($number);` This will convert it into desired format.